# Data validation without loosing values entered in the form by user

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp-2.3

Lets us consider a simple registrations form with fields like username, email, date of birth, password etc.

And there are some data validation rules applied like:

```
'email'=>array(
                'emailrule'=>array(
                    'rule' => 'email',
                    'message' => 'You have entered an invalid e-mail address.'  
                ),
                'isUnique' => array(
                    'rule' => 'isUnique',
                    'message' => 'The e-mail address already exists.',
                ),

            ),
```

When the user submits the form the data gets validated. If invalid the user is redirect to the form  and error is shown to the user. But this time since the page has refreshed the values entered by the user have gone.

is there some way to retain those values??